# How to elegantly log working times by file changes

Tags: windows, date, timestamp

I would like to get to know some (windows) program, or some scripting lines, that could help me to get a chronological list (in the form of a text file) of file changes, on a drive or directory, during the last month. So that i can estimate starting times, and ending times of workdays.

I understand its not a waterproof system, files are overwritten etc. But any way it would be convenient. The principle question would be about doing this in retrospect on an arbitrary system. (Edit: The system is on 24/7) But if there are good tools to install, that can aid this functionality for the future i would also welcume such suggestions.

Comment: If you are shutting down your computer every evening, you could better check the Windows event log for startup/shutdown events. That's the way I once did it. I wrote a program for that, but PowerShell should be possible to do that too.

Comment: Look at Security Auditing   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/325.advanced-security-auditing-in-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx